# Send form for one page

Tags: javascript, html

I would send form to one-page login and password https://rotaexata.centralizee.com/usuarios/login

**communication between http and https login form**

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:2px; margin-left:35px;color: #FFF;"><img src="images/saiba_veiculo.png"   /><p>Rota Exata</p></div>
    <div style="margin-top:2px;">

      <form name="frmLogin2" id="UsuarioLoginForm" action="https://rotaexata.centralizee.com/usuarios/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>
        <div class="textorodape" style="margin-left:10px; padding-bottom:3px; text-align:right; font-size: 12px;">Login:
          <input type="text" id="UsuarioEmail" name="UsuarioEmail" class="inputLogin" />
        </div>
        <div class="textorodape" style="margin-left:10px; padding-bottom:3px; text-align:right;"><span style="font-size: 12px">Senha</span>:
          <input type="password" id="UsuarioSenha" name="UsuarioSenha" class="inputLogin"/>
        </div>
        <div class="textorodape" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px; padding-bottom:3px; text-align:right;"> <a href="mailto:contato@rastreacar.com.br" style="color: #1C0101; font-weight: bold;" >Esqueceu a senha?</a>
          <input name="btnEntrar" type="submit" class="inputButtonLogin" value="Entrar"  onclick="log3();"/>
             </div>

      </form>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function log3(){
document.frmLogin.action='https://rotaexata.centralizee.com/usuarios/login';
documento.frmLogin.submit();
}
```

Comment: Are you using javascript or php?

Comment: JavaScript

function log3(){
document.frmLogin.action='https://rotaexata.centralizee.com/usuarios/login';
documento.frmLogin.submit();
}

Comment: It seems like the names aren't the same on your markup and JavaScript. Also, I don't see how this is a one page as you really submit the form to another page (or is it the same page?)

Comment: submit the form to another page

Answer (score 0):

Your form specifies: `name="frmLogin2"`, but your JavaScript searchs for `frmLogin`. Also a simple `POST` to the login page should be enough, you can leave the action empty and it will send it to the same page.

Then you could ask something like:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnLogin"]))
{
   //Do login stuff here, if credentials are correct, redirect.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but even so the data is not being sent removed the onclick = "log3 ();

Comment: @Benhuragmf, so `var_dump($_POST)` prints `empty`?.